# ReferenceError for a declared function which is for exporting to other files

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a file called `a.js`, and here is the content in it.

```
exports.greeting = function() greeting(){
  console.log("hello");
}

greeting();
```

However it pops up following error when I run it.

```
ReferenceError: greeting is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fred/js_play/a.js:5:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:194:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:618:3
```

it runs perfect when I removed `exports.greeting`. So I wonder how can I make the `greeting()` works both on this file and exportable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just call it (from the current file), like below:

```
exports.greeting();
```

Alternatively, you can do the following:

```
var greeting = function() {
  console.log("hello");
}

//Call the function
greeting();

//Export the function
exports.greeting = greeting;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems to be incorrect. You can try declaring the named function first and then invoke it/assign it to the exports object separately.

```
function greeting(){
    console.log("hello");
}

greeting();

exports.greeting = greeting;
```